# Raspberry Pi configuration address change

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am recently trying to communicate between Arduino and RPi. And I realized that my address was wrong, so I decided to change mine from 0x0f to 0x0c.

How can I do that?

Comment: This question is lacking specifics and detail. How are your Arduino and RPi (supposed to be) communicating? Please update with more details about your setup and what you have tried so far. Moreover, kindly see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are the two connected?